# Калькулятор прибыли на Vanilla JS: проблема при выводе результата при клике

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема, почему не работает код? 
Суть в следующем: нужно при получения значений value у input, по формуле посчитать результат и выводить его при клике на кнопку.

[Код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmLqjces/17/)

JS изучаю с недавних пор, запуталась в коде:)

```
var getValue = 0;
var getProductivity = 0;
var getCost = 0;
var getArea = 0;
var profit = 0;
var result = 0;

var select = document.getElementById('agriculture');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getValue = this.value;
});

var productivity = document.getElementById('productivity');

productivity.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getProductivity = this.value;
});

var cost = document.getElementById('cost');

cost.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getCost = this.value;
});

var area = document.getElementById('area');

area.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getArea = this.value;
});

// profit = (select * productivity) - (cost * area);

document.getElementById('getResult').innerHTML = result;

var calcProfit = document.getElementById('calcProfit');

calcProfit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var profit = (getValue * getProductivity) - (getCost * getArea);
});

console.log(profit);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, главная ошибка в том, что если просто написать в коде

```
document.getElementById('getResult').innerHTML = profit;
console.log(profit);
```

Он один раз отработает, когда браузер будет "читать" скрипт и всё... от этого он дальше не станет каждый раз обновляться, когда profit будет менять значение. Чтобы обновлять innerHTML - этот код нужно разместить внутри функции, которая каждый раз будет вызываться при клике и каждый раз обновлять числа ( [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/hj5oeu8t/2/) ):

```js
var getValue = 0;
var getProductivity = 0;
var getCost = 0;
var getArea = 0;
var profit = 0;
var result = 0;

var select = document.getElementById('agriculture');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getValue = this.value;
});

var productivity = document.getElementById('productivity');

productivity.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getProductivity = this.value;
});

var cost = document.getElementById('cost');

cost.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getCost = this.value;
});

var area = document.getElementById('area');

area.addEventListener('change', function() {
  getArea = this.value;
});

// profit = (select * productivity) - (cost * area);

var calcProfit = document.getElementById('calcProfit');

calcProfit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var profit = (getValue * getProductivity) - (getCost * getArea);
  document.getElementById('getResult').innerHTML = profit;
  console.log(profit);
});
```

```css
.calculator {
  min-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e7e4e4;
  border: 2px dotted #0003bd;
}

.calculator .calc-header p {
  color: #25383f;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calculator .calc-header .calc-text-header {
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  color: #25383f;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form p {
  color: #25383f;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #cecdcd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.calculator .calc-formula form input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form select {
  width: 250px;
  color: #25383f;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #cecdcd;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form select option {
  color: #25383f;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.calculator .calc-result p {
  color: #d26441;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.calculator .calc-result .result {
  color: #d26441;
  font-size: 47px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.calculator .calc-result .currency {
  color: #25383f;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.calculator .calc-result button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calc-header">
    <p>Посчитайте</p>
    <p>Прибыль</p>
    <p class="calc-text-header">Добриво эффективнее химии</p>
  </div>
  <div class="calc-formula">
    <form action="" name="agroCalculator">
      <p>Выберите культуру</p>
      <select id="agriculture">
        <option value="3100">Пшеница ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="2500">Овес ≈ 2500 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="3100">Рожь ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="2400">Кукуруза ≈ 2400 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="1850">Просо ≈ 1850 грн / т"</option>
      </select>
      <p>Урожайность, ц/га</p>
      <input type="number" name="" id="productivity" placeholder="20">
      <p>Стоимость хим. удобрения, грн/га</p>
      <input type="number" name="" id="cost" placeholder="3000">
      <p>Посевная площадь, га</p>
      <input type="number" name="" id="area" placeholder="10">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="calc-result">
    <p>Прибыль от добрива</p>
    <p class="result" id="getResult"></p>
    <p class="currency">грн</p>
    <button id="calcProfit">Рассчитать прибыль</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

А если результат не будет обновляться после каждого ввода `oninput`, а только при клике - то можно и не записывать все значения в отдельные переменные, а при клике сразу собрать все значения из всех полей, так ( [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/wcge8k67/) ):

```js
var agriculture  = $id('agriculture');
var productivity = $id('productivity');
var cost         = $id('cost');
var area         = $id('area');
var result       = $id('getResult');

document.getElementById('calcProfit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var profit = (agriculture.value * productivity.value) - (cost.value * area.value);
  result.innerText = profit; // Там нет HTML-кода, поэтому innerText
  console.log(profit);
});

/******************/

function $id(id){
  return document.getElementById(id); 
}
```

```css
.calculator {
  min-width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e7e4e4;
  border: 2px dotted #0003bd;
}

.calculator .calc-header p {
  color: #25383f;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calculator .calc-header .calc-text-header {
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  color: #25383f;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form p {
  color: #25383f;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #cecdcd;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.calculator .calc-formula form input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form select {
  width: 250px;
  color: #25383f;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #cecdcd;
}

.calculator .calc-formula form select option {
  color: #25383f;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.calculator .calc-result p {
  color: #d26441;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.calculator .calc-result .result {
  color: #d26441;
  font-size: 47px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.calculator .calc-result .currency {
  color: #25383f;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
}

.calculator .calc-result button {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calc-header">
    <p>Посчитайте</p>
    <p>Прибыль</p>
    <p class="calc-text-header">Добриво эффективнее химии</p>
  </div>
  <div class="calc-formula">
    <form action="" name="agroCalculator">
      <p>Выберите культуру</p>
      <select id="agriculture">
        <option value="3100">Пшеница ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="2500">Овес ≈ 2500 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="3100">Рожь ≈ 3100 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="2400">Кукуруза ≈ 2400 грн / т"</option>
        <option value="1850">Просо ≈ 1850 грн / т"</option>
      </select>
      <p>Урожайность, ц/га</p>
      <input type="number" name="" id="productivity" placeholder="20">
      <p>Стоимость хим. удобрения, грн/га</p>
      <input type="number" name="" id="cost" placeholder="3000">
      <p>Посевная площадь, га</p>
      <input type="number" name="" id="area" placeholder="10">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="calc-result">
    <p>Прибыль от добрива</p>
    <p class="result" id="getResult"></p>
    <p class="currency">грн</p>
    <button id="calcProfit">Рассчитать прибыль</button>
  </div>
</div>
```